# Reading page line by line and getting blocked by page

Tags: ip, readline

I have a simple program that goes to a webpage and reads its text line by line (i would prefer read whole page in 1 shot but dont know how to do that). This is basicly the same as when i open the web page in my browser. This program doesn't do anything harmful and basicaly simulates how user would browse a webpage. What is odd though is that while i never get blocked browsing that page, my program does get ip blocked. There is clearly something that i don't understand about the way readLine vs chrome browsing works and i would like some help. Like i said my code works, the only problem is website for some reason thinks i am trying to do something bad and blocks my ip. Here is example of the code with which i read text from a web page.

```
String temp;

    try {           
        URL oracle;
        oracle = new URL(url);          
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        int line = 0;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {                                       

             // do something    

        }       
                in.close();             
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("error: ");
            System.out.println(e);      
        }
```

Comment: Anyone ? Help ?

Comment: Anyone ? Help ?